# Images of Fullscreen slider doesn't get 100vh and 100vw on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created [this](https://codepen.io/amankha04763571/pen/ExgOVQj) fullscreen slider where each image of slide has a full width and height that takes the entire screen but couldn't make the images to get full width and height when resizing the browser.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <button id="prevBtn"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i> Previous</button>
  <button id="nextBtn"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Next</button>
  <div class="slides-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash...." alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://images...." alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://images...." alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

each of above images has following css styles attached to it:

```
.slides-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

I tried this approach which works well, but I don't want to refresh the browser on window resize:

```
window.onresize = function () {
  location.reload();
};
```

The problem could be noticed in JavaScript file where this variable `const slideWidth = slides[0].clientWidth;` is not updated on window resize. here is the JS code:

```
const slideWidth = slides[0].clientWidth;

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nextSlide();
});

function nextSlide() {
  slidesContainer.style.transition = "all 0.3s ease-in-out";

  index++;
  slidesContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${
    -slideWidth * (index + 1)
  }px)`;

  if (index > slides.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      index = 0;
      slidesContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${-slideWidth}px)`;
      slidesContainer.style.transition = "none";
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

full code avaialble [here](https://codepen.io/amankha04763571/pen/ExgOVQj?editors=0010). Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `100vw` instead of setting `slideWidth` to pixels.

At the start make `slideWidth = 100` then in each time you set the transformX, use vw instead of pixels

Example

```
slidesContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${
  -slideWidth * (index + 1)
}px)`;
```

to

```
slidesContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${
  -slideWidth * (index + 1)
}vw)`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You used px in slidewidth, try use the vw not px